# Group policy not working on all domain computers unless rejoin to domain

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I use Windows Server 2012 R2 and all my desktops are domain joined.
Whenever I create any Group Policy ,it does not work unless I remove the PC from Domain and rejoin them.
After rejoining to domain, group policies work without any issue.
FYI, I have disabled DHCP on server and enabled on Firewall.
Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why this may not be working as you expect.

The first thing I would suggest to try is opening the command prompt on these PCs and typing gpupdate -force

Command prompt will usually ask you to restart to apply to changes to computer policy, type y and enter to restart. After this your new group policies should be applied.

Another thing to consider is that when you re-add computers to the domain they are automatically added to the Computers OU. It could be that this is where your group policies are being applied to and that before that they were in a different OU in which the group policies are not applied.

Hope this helps, let me know how you get on.